# The triangle made of asterisks

Tags: java, input, geometry

I saw a few post on this already but I don't seem to understand what the problem is. I am very new at this and I just can't figure this out. I have to make a triangle made of asterisk for a homework. The number of rows wille be determined by which integer the user inputs and show give something like this

```
*
**
***
****
```

I'm not really sure how to do this. But this is what I have so far (pretty sure I made dumb errors)

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class triangle {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*declarations*/
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        int how_many;/*number of rows*/
        int i;
        int j;
        /*prompt for input*/
        System.out.printIn("Choissiez un nombre entier postif");
        how_many=input.nextInt();
    }
        for(i=1;i<=1;i++){
            for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.printIn();
        }

}
```

Comment: You never use `how_many` in your nested loops.

Comment: and also check your braces (`{` and `}`). You have a closing brace before your `for` loop, which is a syntax error before your `for` loops

Comment: What should I use if I dont use how_many?

Comment: You mean 'println' rather than 'printIn'.  Fix that and the braces and this will, at least, compile.

Comment: @ZouZou said you are not using how_many, when you should. What will this line do? `for(i=1;i<=1;i++){` How many times will it loop?  How many times do you want it too?

Comment: @Cherry You should use `how_many` to print the figure you want (based on the user input). ATM, you're only printing one row, whatever the input is.

Comment: it's println, all lower case, not printIn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write your code.  Keep the opening and closing brackets `{   }`  on the same line.

It's easier to read you code.

Also, you'll be able to see where you're code is.

This is your code formatted to the best of my ability.

```
public class triangle
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        /*declarations*/
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

        /*
         * No need to create this variable here.
         * Just create a variable when you need it.
         *
        int how_many;/*number of rows/
         */

        /*
         * The i and j variables can be declared right within the 
         *  for loop.
         * 
        int i;
        int j;
         */

        /*
         * It's println, not printIn
         */
        /*prompt for input*/
        System.out.println("Choissiez un nombre entier postif");

        /*
         * You can just create the variable right here, int how_many
         */
        int how_many=input.nextInt();

        /*
         * This for loop is doing nothing. It runs once, thats it.
         * 
         * You want it to loop as many times as the user entered
         *  
        for(int i = 1 ; i <= 1 ; i++)
         */
        for(int i = 1 ; i <= how_many ; i++)
        {
            /*
             * In this nested loop you need to print out the number of
             *  asterisks depending on the iteration of the parent loop
             * 
            for(int j=1; j<=i; j++)
             */
            for(int j = 1 ; j <= i ; j++)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    /*
     * This entire for loop is not within any method.
     * 
     * You need to bring it a few lines
     * 
    for(i=1;i<=1;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        System.out.printIn();
    }
     */
}
```

Or

```
public class triangle
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Choissiez un nombre entier postif");

        int how_many = input.nextInt();

        for(int i = 1; i <= how_many; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Or

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.println("Choissiez un nombre entier postif");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int how_many = input.nextInt();

    for(int i = 1; i <= how_many; i++)
        System.out.println(String.format("%0" + i + "d", 0).replace("0", "*"));

    input.close();
}
```

Best I could get

```
public class triangle
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int n = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        while(n != 0)
            System.out.println(String.format("%0" + n-- + "d", 0).replace("0", "*"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class triangle {
    public static void main( final String args[] ) {
/*declarations*/
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        int how_many;/*number of rows*/
        int i;
        int j;
/*promt for input*/
        System.out.println( "Choissiez un nombre entier postif" );
        how_many = input.nextInt();
        for( i = 1; i <= how_many; i++ ) {
            for( j = 1; j <= i; j++ ) {
                System.out.print( "*" );
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Using jdk 7.

The main algorithmic issues being that you need to set `i <= how_many` and `j <= i`

Comment: I've got no compiler errors, or I would not have posted it.

Comment: -1 care to explain? This is the solution with insight as to what was wrong.

Comment: this is what I get when I run my code through ideone.com to see what errors come up. [link](http://imgur.com/CRsjlyY)

Comment: only copy the main method and don't forget to set the input [link](http://ideone.com/h6bypR)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code for a similar project that I had a few years back. You'll have to add a main, but that shouldn't be too difficult. This code is working and pretty self-explanatory. Let me know if you have any questions :)

```
public class TriangleTwo
{
    private int size; //size
    private String letter; //symbol or letter

public TriangleTwo()
{

}

public TriangleTwo(int count, String let)
{
    setTriangle(count, let);
}

public void setTriangle(int count, String let)
{
    size = count;
    letter = let;
}

public String getLetter()
{
    return "*"; //you can change the symbol that is printed
}

public String toString()
{
    String output="";
    for(int i = size; i >= 1; i--) // transverse through col
    {
        for(int x = i; x >= 1; x--) // transverse through row
        {    
            output += letter; // will print the letter that you chose
        }
        output += "\n"; // skips a line
    }
    return output + "\n"; // prints triangle
}
}
```